# Why is this jQuery returning true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Here's my code that isn't working (it's returning true) and submits my form even with validation errors:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#post").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            $("#publish").removeClass("button-primary-disabled");
            $('#ajax-loading').hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This code will return false just fine and works as it should:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#post").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Why isn't the first one working?

EDIT 1: Removed trailing commas, but they weren't the problem.

EDIT 2: In case it matters, I am using this to validate a custom post type entry form in the wordpress admin. Still doesn't explain why one works and the other doesn't. :/

EDIT 3: It appears leaving out "return false" also works the same as leaving it in.

NEW QUESTION: How do I keep this default functionality of returning invalid (not submitting the form and returning standard error messages) but also modify my two elements?

Comment: Do you have any rules defined?

Comment: The rules are what determine what data needs to be validated and if one returns false the invalidHandler then gets fired

Comment: My guess is that either "publish" or "ajax-loading" are undefined Id's. Check your HTML or try displaying $("#publish").length and $("#ajax-loading").length to be sure.

Comment: @rontornambe. Juqery was designed to work with 0+ selected elements. it's NOT that for sure.

Comment: I notice you've used `jQuery()` in the first couple of lines of code, but then you've used the `$()` alias on the lines that break the function. Have you called the `jQuery.noConflict()` method or included some other library that also tries to define `$` or created your own variable named `$` (any of which would result in an error when you then try to use `$()` as `jQuery()`)?

Comment: It would really help if you can post a simplified complete test case on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your code, I do notice that there is a syntax error after your `invalidHandler` function: there is a trailing comma.

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#post").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            $("#publish").removeClass("button-primary-disabled");
            $('#ajax-loading').hide();
            return false;
        } 
    });
});
```

Also, what does the form do when leaving out the `return false`? I don't see anything in the docs about that actually doing anything. By the time execution reaches this point, the submission of the form should already be cancelled.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Comment: Thanks for that catch. But it still acts the same either way.

Comment: Where is *a trailing comma*? It's the same as the second one.

Comment: @Eli Ah ha! Leaving out everything within invalidHandler, including "return false;" is giving me the same results as leaving "return false;" in there.

Sooo, how do I get those two elements modified when a form is invalid AND get this default behavior?